# Error Could not cast value of type UIView to SKview

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview, iad, skscene

Ever since i added in iAds i keep getting this error. "could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x196afa530) to 'SKView' (0x19685f560)."

this is the code that fails and the code on the bottom is my inter view controller code.. which is not much.
i think at also has something to do with this code for iAds.

```
    var interstitialAdView: UIView = UIView()
```

Code:

```
 override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
         let skView = self.view as! SKView
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
            skView.showsFPS = false
            skView.showsNodeCount = false
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            let scene: SKScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
            skView.presentScene(scene)
       }
    }
```

All ViewController code:

```
  import UIKit
  import StoreKit
  import SpriteKit
  import GameKit
  import iAd

 extension SKNode {
class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) -> SKNode? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
        var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    } else {
        return nil
    }
  }

}

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADInterstitialAdDelegate{
var interstitialAd:ADInterstitialAd!

var interstitialAdView: UIView = UIView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    loadInterstitialAd()

    ADBannerView()


    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!)
    {
        gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }




    var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in

        if (viewController != nil) {
            let vc: UIViewController = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
            vc.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else {
            println((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))

        }
    }





}
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
         let skView = self.view as! SKView
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
            skView.showsFPS = false
            skView.showsNodeCount = false
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            let scene: SKScene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
            skView.presentScene(scene)



  }

}



override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

func loadInterstitialAd() {

    interstitialAd = ADInterstitialAd()

    interstitialAd.delegate = self





     }



func interstitialAdWillLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {



}



func interstitialAdDidLoad(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {







    interstitialAdView = ADBannerView()

    interstitialAdView.frame = CGRectZero

    self.interstitialAdView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-self.interstitialAdView.frame.size.height, self.interstitialAdView.frame.size.width, self.interstitialAdView.frame.size.height)

    interstitialAdView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    self.view .addSubview(interstitialAdView)





    interstitialAd.presentInView(interstitialAdView)

    UIViewController.prepareInterstitialAds()

}



func interstitialAdActionDidFinish(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {

    interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()



}



func interstitialAdActionShouldBegin(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {

    return true

}



func interstitialAd(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println(" iAds Did Fail with Error")


}



func interstitialAdDidUnload(interstitialAd: ADInterstitialAd!) {

    interstitialAdView.removeFromSuperview()

}



   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me. All you have to do is transfer all your iAd code to your GameScene.swift and change self into self.view!.window!.rootViewController! wherever there is an error.