# Swift Could not cast value of type 'UIView' to 'SKView'

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

First, I've reviewed the related questions:

- [Error Could not cast value of type UIView to SKview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724055/error-could-not-cast-value-of-type-uiview-to-skview)
- [Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1102beb40) to 'SKView' (0x10f0814c8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40199023/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uiview-0x1102beb40-to-skview-0x10f0814c8)
- [Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x112484eb0) to 'SKView' (0x111646718)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30792196/could-not-cast-value-of-type-uiview-0x112484eb0-to-skview-0x111646718)

None of those provided a clear answer for me, I'm unable to present a controller that has an `SKView` in it from my main `ViewController`, example:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var sceneView: SCNView!
  var gameScene = GameScene()
  var spriteScene: OverlayScene!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    sceneView.scene = gameScene
  }

  func showModal() {
    let popupViewController = PopupViewController()
    popupViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    present(popupViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }  
}
```

But the issue seems to be when the `PopupViewController` is called:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class PopupViewController:UIViewController {
  var sceneView:SKView!
  var spriteScene:PopupScene!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    view.scene = spriteScene

    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

The error is raised:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1b48c69c8) to 'SKView' (0x1b3b254b0).
```

Comment: I am just quickly glancing at this, but the PopupViewController is a UIViewController. I don't work with scenes too much- but it looks like instead of setting the scene of the 'sceneView' on 'PopupViewController', you are setting the scene on the view(which is a UIView by default). So you may need to set up that 'sceneView' and then set the scene on that?

Comment: Yeah, `view` in a `UIViewController` is a `UIView`. Looks like you need to set `view = sceneView` in `loadView` or `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thinking a little more, it probably needs to happen in `loadView`. Not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your answer, you appear to be using the main `view` of your `PopupViewController` to add the scene to, rather than the new `sceneView` that you declared. The first way to fix this is, as said by Nathan Hitchings in the comments, to override `loadView` and set `self.view = sceneView`. The other option is to open your storyboard or .xib and set the class type of the main view to be `SKView` and then you can delete the `sceneView` variable entirely and work with `self.view`. Both essentially do the same thing, but in two different ways. Ensure that you give `sceneView` a value before using it too, as currently it appears to stay uninitialised. Let me know if you need me to clarify anything.

The first option would look something like this:

```
override func loadView() {
    sceneView = SKView()
    sceneView.backgroundColor = .white

    self.view = sceneView
}
```